# Stop event listeners from firing when the user changes the tab and comes back

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am making a game in JavaScript, in which the player is controlled by arrow keys.

If the user presses the arrow keys and changes the tab simultaneously, when they come back to the tab, the player is still moving due to the event listener firing `keydown` without noticing the `keyup` after the user has changed the tab.

How will I be able to *stop the events from firing after the user switches the tab and comes back?*

In other words, **how would I make sure that after the user switches the tab and comes back, the player isn't moving based on the arrow keys that were held priorly?**

Here is a sample I made to present the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/mgh38d1e/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var player = {x: 0, y: 0};

function loop() {
  // draw background
 ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // draw player
 ctx.fillStyle = 'lawngreen';
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 50, 50);
  
  if(right) player.x += 1;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();

var right = false;

addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
 if(e.key == 'd')
   right = true;
});

addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
 if(e.key == 'd')
   right = false;
});
```

```html
<h1>Press D to move right</h1>
<canvas id="game" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: How about you just clear the key-down flags upon losing focus? The key-handler could set and clear them, the handler when you lose focus could also clear them.

Comment: Would it work to simply add a pause screen that is closed with a different button/click?

Comment: @Altigraph quite possibly, but there has to be an easier way of approaching this. All I need to make sure of is that the event listeners stop whenever the user changes the tab and comes back.

Comment: What do you mean by "The keydown event simply runs again as soon as the user comes back on the tab "? Are you saying that even if the key is not pressed anymore more `keydown` event are beong genrated? What browser does this? I can't repro on FF&Chrome https://jsfiddle.net/9js752gb/

Comment: @Kaiido here, I posted a sample of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/mgh38d1e/

Comment: Can you show what code you have attempted to use on loss of focus?

Comment: Just check out this little test fiddle I made that demonstrates this exact issue: https://jsfiddle.net/mgh38d1e/

Comment: [MCVE] must be included in the question itself. And that still doesn't answer the question in my comment. Here you are not receiving **new** events, but only triggering on a single one. You said in response to @enhzflep proposition that listening for blur wouldn't work because the event do fire again. What makes you say so? Listen for blur [is the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/apd3kcr2/), what makes your case so particular about it?

Comment: @Kaiido I just realized I was indeed using blur, just not using it correctly. User 
enhzflep was right, and this solved my problem. Either way, this should probably be posted as an answer.

Comment: I agree, @enhzflep if you're still around, do you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sort of thing I had in mind.

```js
function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}

function newEl(tag) {
  return document.createElement(tag)
}

function qsa(sel, par = document) {
  return par.querySelectorAll(sel)
}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

class kbKey {
  constructor(name, keyCode) {
    this.name = name;
    this.keyCode = keyCode;
    return this;
  }
}

var keys = [];

var arrowKeys = [
  [null, new kbKey('^', 38), null],
  [new kbKey('<', 37), new kbKey('V', 40), new kbKey('>', 39), ]
];

var numPad = [
  [new kbKey('7', 103), new kbKey('8', 104), new kbKey('9', 105)],
  [new kbKey('4', 100), new kbKey('5', 101), new kbKey('6', 102)],
  [new kbKey('1', 97), new kbKey('2', 98), new kbKey('3', 99)],
  [new kbKey('>', 39), new kbKey('0', 96), new kbKey('.', 110)]
];

function onLoaded(evt) {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', onkeydown, false);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', onkeyup, false);

  window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus, false);
  window.addEventListener('blur', onBlur, false);

  keys = keys.fill(false);

  drawKeys(numPad);
}

function onkeydown(evt) {
  keys[evt.keyCode] = true;
  // console.log(evt.key, evt.which);
  updateDisplay();
}

function onkeyup(evt) {
  keys[evt.keyCode] = false;
  updateDisplay();
}

function onBlur(evt) {
  keys = keys.fill(false);
}

function onFocus(evt) {
  updateDisplay();
}

function updateDisplay() {
  let cells = Array.from(qsa('#keyboard td'));

  cells.forEach(
    function(cell, index, collection) {
      if (cell.dataset.code != undefined) {
        if (keys[parseInt(cell.dataset.code)] == true)
          cell.classList.add('active');
        else
          cell.classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
  );
}

function drawKeys(keydata2D) {
  let tbl = byId('keyboard');

  keydata2D.forEach(function(rowArray, rowIndex, rowCollection) {
    let tr = newEl('tr');

    rowArray.forEach(
      function(key, col, keyArray) {
        let td = newEl('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
        if (key != null) {
          td.textContent = key.name;
          td.dataset.code = key.keyCode;
        }
      }
    );
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
  });
}
```

```css
td[data-code] {
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ffad68;
}
```

```html
<table id='keyboard'></table>
```